# Unfocus quill's text editor

Tags: javascript, focus, rich-text-editor, quill

Is there a way to unfocus?

I want to update the whole text format using my code and i don't want to give my user the option to write text after it.
I update the format of the whole text (range: start=0, end=text length) using formatText method and then the text area on focus and the user can write:/

Comment: Hi(: can you help me? @jhchen

Comment: So you want the user to highlight text and format it but not type (insert or delete text)?

Comment: No.. I edited my question to be more clear.. I don't want to highlight text.. i want to update the format of the whole text.

Comment: The confusing part for me is "and then the text area on focus and the user can write". Can you rephrase?

Comment: when the text area on focus- the user can edit the text (write or delete the text).. i don't want to give him that option. i want to give him the ability to change just the format of the whole text.
So, after i'm changing the format of the text using my code, i would like to unfocus the text area. 
there is a focus method.. is there a way to unfocus?

Answer (score 4):

There is not an explicit `unfocus()` API since there's not much that Quill needs beyond the existing DOM blur function:

```
quill.root.blur()
```

The user can of course click back into the editor so if you want to prevent that you can disable the whole editor with:

```
quill.editor.disable()
```

You may still make API calls but the user will be unable to interact with the editor while disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with the cursor remaining on the screen after blur.  I realized that quill already has a hidden focusable element that seems to fix the problem.

quill.querySelector('.ql-clipboard').focus();